# Can Stack Exchange sites send notifications that work with App Tabs in Firefox?

Tags: feature-request, firefox, ajax

Is it possible to use App Tabs in Firefox 5 to send notifications about new comments/posts to your questions?

An App Tab in Firefox is highlighted blue when its website title has changed (e.g. Gmail).

I would like to use this feature on the Stack Exchange sites. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems unlikely since Stack Exchange already doesn't show data live -- your inbox doesn't light up as soon as you get a notification, you need to load a new page.

It's more likely this could be folded into a user script like [SO Live!](https://stackapps.com/questions/1703/so-live-live-updates-to-your-reputation-score) that already does live page updating. I don't know if a script like that exists for inbox notifications (SO Live! only does reputation, I think)