# Highlight browser tab on notification

Tags: feature-request, notifications

I suggest that the browser tab gets highlighted every time a notification happens.

This can be done by changing the title of the page when a notification happens. It should be for inbox and achievements in the new bar, possibly also for other notifications that I am not aware of.

I have searched on this before posting and found the following topic: [Can Stack Exchange sites send notifications that work with App Tabs in Firefox?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105725/can-stack-exchange-sites-send-notifications-that-work-with-app-tabs-in-firefox)

However I am under the impression that notifications are handled live currently.

**EDIT**: I found another topic on the same matter that seems to have died down aswell: [Notifications in browser tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140151/notifications-in-browser-tab?rq=1)

Comment: Welcome to the graveyard :-D